# Mathematical Problems of General Relativity II

Tags: reference-request, books, general-relativity

In the introduction of D. Christodoulou's book ["Mathematical Problems of General Relativity I"](https://bookstore.ams.org/emszlec-6/), he refers a few times to the second volume. My question is does it exists? Has it been (or will it be) published yet (possibly under a different title)?

Comment: Isn't this a question best directed to the author?  A quick google search pulls up his e-mail address.

Comment: @RyanBudney I suppose you are right, but doesn't your comment apply to all reference questions about papers/books with a living arthor.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  You are asking about the intentions of a particular author -- that's a personal question.   You can ask all kinds of reference questions about particular authors that avoid personal questions.

Comment: No, I am asking whether that volume exists. That is objective, not personal, and many people, besides the author, could answer that.

Comment: @RyanBudney Also, a private message from the author will not make the answer publically available. However, I wonder whether the question is a better fit for Physics.StackExchange.

Comment: @M.Winter, these books by Christodoulou is without a doubt mathematics books.